# Integrate Livechat System xritten in Codeigniter in Cakephp installation

Tags: codeigniter, cakephp, livechat

I have gotten a live chat system written in codeigniter, and I want to integrate my WebSite, which is written in Cakephp him.

I installed the "/ livechat" folder webroot, I modified the livechat file / application / config / config.php and I put :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://exemple.com/livechat/';
```

Then I modified the .htaccess file in the folder "/livechat" :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /livechat
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1
```

But when I run the live chat with the address "http://exemple.com/livechat/" I get an error: 404 Page Not Found

Can someone help me please?

thank you in advance

Comment: Have you checked the route file?

Comment: Route file is to redirect a URL to a controller, it's not my goal

Comment: Yhe Index.php page located in "/livechat" folder run, but it gets stuck in calls to Codeigniter files I think, because the page 404 is personalized with the styles of the system Livechat

Comment: Usually I use this to disallow the rewrite of folder and files. `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt)` where `public`is a folder.